# Vectorized if_else or case_when which doesn't eagerly evaluate its potential outputs?

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

`dplyr` has the vectorized conditionals `if_else` and `case_when`.

However, both of these eagerly evaluate their possible outputs (`true/false` for `if_else`, the RHS of the formula for `case_when`):

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

if_else(c(T, T, T), print(1), print(2))
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 1 1 1

case_when(
  c(T, T, T) ~ print(1),
  c(F, F, F) ~ print(2)
)
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Here we can obviously see the `false` cases are evaluated even though they're never used. I'm looking for a way to avoid this since my

Is there an alternative which doesn't do this?

I'm aware, one alternative is actually `base::ifelse`:

```r
ifelse(c(T, T, T), print(1), print(2))
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1 1 1
```

However `base::ifelse` is notoriously inefficient, so a better alternative would be nice. That being said, I'm especially interested in alternatives for `case_when`, which I use quite a bit when I'd otherwise need to use a chain of `ifelse`s.

I've already looked at `data.table::fifelse`, but it suffers from the same problem:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(data.table)
})

fifelse(c(T, T, T), print(1), print(2))
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 1 1 1
```

So, is there an alternative for `if_else` and `case_when` which doesn't eagerly evaluate its unused cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the development version of `data.table` from GitHub you can use `fcase` which is similar to `dplyr::case_when` but with lazy evaluation:

```
data.table::fcase(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), print(1L), c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), print(2L))

[1] 1
[1] 1 1 1
```

Comment: Interesting `data.table::fifelse` is not lazy but `fcase` is

Comment: Indeed - especially since it is the same person behind. Perhaps one of `data.table` developers will stop by and explain the functioning more in detail, am happy to delete my post not to duplicate - in any case really great to have it, was one of the reasons why I've been using `dplyr` more often since there wasn't any really similar functionality

Answer (score 3):

You could just rely on native R's lazy evaluation of parameter passing and use `all` to screen for cases when `FALSE` isn't present:

```
lazy_if_else <- function(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
{
  if(all(logical_test)) return(rep(value_if_true, length.out = length(logical_test)))
  if_else(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
}
```

This out-performs `ifelse` and `if_else`

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ifelse(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1)),
                               if_else(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1)),
                               lazy_if_else(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1)))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                                         expr        min         lq         mean
#>        ifelse(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1))     12.662     13.689     25.47675
#>       if_else(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1)) 102723.054 109145.897 109678.33523
#>  lazy_if_else(c(T, T, T), 0, Sys.sleep(0.1))      4.791      5.476     10.80378
#>       median         uq        max neval cld
#>      15.3995     34.904     74.255   100  a 
#>  110036.0945 110176.049 116619.936   100   b
#>       6.5030     16.768     26.008   100  a
```

Comment: This would need to be modified to handle non-single-value `value_if_true`, but is a pretty decent idea.

Comment: @Wasabi do you mean throw an error? That's what `if_else` does. `if_else(c(T,T,T), c(1,2), c(2,3))
Error: 'true' must be length 3 (length of 'condition') or one, not 2` . This is different from `ifelse` which just recycles.

Comment: @Wasabi I've changed it so it now mimics the behaviour of `ifelse`. The benchmarks don't change much.